# Slowness when navigating through explorer view

Tags: open-with-explorer

I sometimes use Open with Explorer to navigate through our file structure. It is painfully slow. 
My IT company say this is because you shouldn't use the Open with Explorer view and should just use the SharePoint interface but this is impractical in some cases (such as moving files, inserting multiple attachments/hyperlinks in emails).
I don't understand why Microsoft would include this feature if it shouldn't be used.

I have turned off 'Automatically detect settings' in Internet Options

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use it, it's just slow because it's not a file system, it just appears to you that it is. It isn't writing to a hard drive. It's pushing the content to the database, and every time you add, change, move, or delete a file, that call has to go back to the database. It's not as simple (and obviously not as quick) as Windows Explorer with your file system.

Microsoft provided the feature because of familiarity for the end user, but also for copying multiple files at once (rather than downloading each individually). It may take just as long to download the files, but there is less action required by the end user.